# Cannot find or open the PDB file message in using of C# interface to SWI-Prolog

Tags: c#, ffi, swi-prolog

I want to use C# interface to SWI-Prolog. so I add the SwiPlCs.dll to project references and set SWI_HOME_DIR environment variable but when i test my application with this sample in [here](http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/Index.aspx),I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

And the output from debug show:

> The thread 0x1bec has exited with code 259 (0x103).
>
> 'swicall.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: swicall.vshost.exe): Loaded 'G:\testingpro\MYAPP\swicall\bin\Debug\swicall.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>
> 'swicall.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: swicall.vshost.exe): Loaded 'G:\testingpro\MyAPP\swicall\bin\Debug\SwiPlCs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> 'swicall.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: swicall.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

IF I copy swi-prolog dll files to my APP directly, [the sample code works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask),but my codes faces with the 'Cannot find or open the PDB file
'message.

**How to can I fix this error?**

other information:
OS:win8-64bit vs:2013-32bit SwiPlCs_1.1.60605.0 Swi-prolog ver7.3.8
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SWI_HOME_DIR", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl")

Comment: You should set `Copy Local` on swi-prolog assembly reference, it will force VS to copy referenced assembly to `bin\Debug` directory. Cannot find PDB error - means that debugger cannot find `.pdb` file associated with SWI-prolog DLL (usually named like dll but with `.pdb` extension). PDB files are used be debuggers to locate and show source files e.g. on unhandled exception, in case when you are using external library you may ignore this error.

Comment: @ csharpfolk : You should set Copy Local on swi-prolog assembly reference,...  I added  SwiPlCs.dll to my refrences but i get An unhandled exception error....

Comment: OK, I was able to reproduce your problem, try to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl\bin` to system `%PATH%`, restart your computer (this is important), then it should work.  Wrapper library was trying to load `libswipl.dll` using WIN32 `LoadLibrary` but cannot find it, hence strange error message.

Comment: I set system %PATH% but without any running error, the  application is exited,and debug output is:  'WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Comment: OK, I see - can you create Console application instead, then run it without debugging and check if it written anything to standard output (console)?

Comment: This message is written in console: SWI-Prolog:[FATAL ERROR: Could not find system resources] Press any key to continue...

Comment: This kind of errors is described in [documentation](http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/Index.aspx), try to uncomment `//Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SWI_HOME_DIR",...` line and check if it points to valid installation directory.

Comment: i set this varable such `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SWI_HOME_DIR", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl\bin") ` but not responsed. i dont know this interface works on vs2013 or up.

Comment: Try set it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl\ ` (without bin)

Comment: Sorry, it don't work.

Comment: thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. I installed the windows symbols from Microsoft site and error resolve. now sample code works fine.